# I am having a service in angular and I have static method in that service. How do I write unit test for static method?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class TestService {
  static testMethod(data: any, file: string) {
    // do some stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: It depends on what your static method does. In a standard case, you would invoke it and then compare the expected result with the actual result.

Comment: Static function in my case is executing some line of code. It's not returning anything.